# unity how to use www to load mp3 file with absolute path on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mp3

I'm making a mobile rhythm game. I get absolute path of song like this.

> /storage/emulated/0/Music/a.mp3

I want to convert the mp3 file to [audioClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-audioClip.html).

But I can't a receive mp3 file from absolute path.

here is my code :

```
IEnumerator GetSoundFile(string path)
{
    //path : '/storage/emulated/0/Music/a.mp3'
    testText.text = path;
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    using (var www = new WWW(path))
    {
        yield return www;
        source.clip = www.GetAudioClip();
    }
    SoundManager.instance.PlaySingle(source.clip);
}
```

How can I receive a music file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the persistent path for android location , Try this
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html

Answer (score 0):

In android, add this function to get correct path:

```
...
path = GetUri(path);
...

private string GetUri(string uri)
{
     if (uri.Contains("://") || uri.Contains(":///"))
         return uri;

     return "file://" + uri;
}
```